# Can @Size hibernate annotation be inherited?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, bean-validation

I am trying to use hibernate validation to check size of a list. in general I want the list to be empty, unless it is an object of type `B`. it seems not to work:

```
public static class A
{
    private List<Integer> inheritedRemoveAnnotation = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Size(max=0)
    public List<Integer> getInheritedRemoveAnnotation()
    {
        return inheritedRemoveAnnotation;
    }
}
public static class B extends A
{
    @Override
    @Size(max=Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    public List<Integer> getInheritedRemoveAnnotation()
    {
        return super.getInheritedRemoveAnnotation();
    }
}

private static Validator m_validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    B b = new B();
    b.getInheritedRemoveAnnotation().add(1);
    System.out.println(m_validator.validate(b));
}
```

The output I get is:
`[ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='size must be between 0 and 0', propertyPath=inheritedRemoveAnnotation, rootBeanClass=class oshai.hibernatevalidators.TestInheritence$B, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}'}]`

Comment: I don't think it's inheritable, but you could check in the annotation's source to see if it has the @Inherited annotation. I'd be surprised if it was.

Comment: I am overriding the getXXX method, isnt in that case the parent method (and its annotations) is ignored?

Comment: Oh, I see-I misunderstood, sorry. I'll look again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the constraints that are somewhere up in hierarchy are also checked. According [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-usingvalidator.html):

> Constraint annotations are aggregated if methods are overridden.